# Running Jstack -F $Thread_NID with Crontab

Tags: shell, unix, cron, jstack

I have created a Unix Shell Script, in which am trying to take Thread dump when cpu usage is above 80%.

For calculation cpu usage am using `mpstat 1 1|tail -1` and geting cpu idle usage out of it.

Then i find top Java Threads based on `top -b -n1 -H`, and use `jstack -F $Thread_Nid`, thread_nid is nothing but pid which we got from `top-b -n1 -H`.

Now the problem is

```
JSTACK_OUTPUT=$(jstack -F $Thread_Nid)

echo "$JSTACK_OUTPUT" >> $logfile
```

works fine when i run the script manually i get the jstack output in logfile, but when i run the script via crontab, Jstack output isn't comming to the log file.

Both manually as well as via Crontab am running script under same username, this i have verified by checking the username in top command when script is running.

Please let me know what am i doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned the script is working well while executing manually and fails in the crontab, it seems like you missed the directory of it. When you keep the script in crontab check whether did you mentioned the path name. 
this is wrong: `30 08 10 06 * backup.sh` 
this is right: `30 08 10 06 * /home/ramesh/full-backup.sh`

Answer (score 0):

As, when we are running from terminal we don't need to pass the full path of java home where the *jstack* package will be there.

Just use this command:

```
#which jstack
```

You will get here jstack path:

```
~/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/jstack
```

Use this in the script:

```
~/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/jstack $pid
```